# What are the main issues in designing an interpreter for a functional language?

Tags: functional-programming, interpreter

Suppose I want to implement an interpreter for a functional language. I would like to understand the issues involved in doing so and suitable literature that is available. This is a new language that is in early design stages, that is why the question is broad in scope.

For the purpose of this discussion we can assume that the purpose of the language is not important and that its functional features can be changed (even drastically) if it makes a significant difference in the ease of writing an interpreter.

The MIT website has an online copy of [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) as well as [videos](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/classes/6.001/abelson-sussman-lectures/) of the MIT 6.001 lectures using Scheme, recorded at HP in 1986. These form a great introduction to language design.

Comment: I'll just gently recommend that you may want to go through your past questions and accept an answer if there is a suitable one for each of them.

Comment: This should really be a community wiki.

Comment: @Bobby - I've done that.

@David - How do I make this a community wiki? If you can do that, please go ahead. I am not especially interested in being a librarian or in the political aspects of garnering reputation points etc.

Comment: @S.Lott - If you tell me where to find this "Community Wiki" button, I can push it now. Otherwise I am more interested in any technical comments you may have about the question at hand.

Comment: @S I: Edit your question.  It was at the bottom when you posted it.  It's there when you edit it.  You can -- if you want -- look at the Stack Overflow help pages.

Comment: @S.Lott: Done making it a CW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would highly recommend [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs (SICP)](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) as a starting point. This book will introduce the idea of what it means to write an interpreter (and a compiler), and is generally a must-read for anybody designing languages.

Implementing an interpreter for a functional language isn't likely to be too much different from implementing an interpreter for any other general purpose language. There's lexical analysis, parsing, AST construction, semantic analysis, plus execution (for a pure interpreter) or code generation and optimisation (for a compiler, even compiling to bytecode like Java/Perl/Python). SICP will introduce the difference between "applicative order" and "normal order" evaluation, which may be important for you in a pure functional context.

Comment: Great. The book and lecture videos are both online and form a fantastic introduction to functional programming and to language design.

Answer (score 1):

For just about any language interpreter or compiler, the main issues are the same, I think.

You need to decide certain basic characteristics of the language (semantics, not syntax), and the bulk of the design of the thing follows from that.

- For example, does your language have
  a type system? If so, what sorts of
  types does it have? Is it going to be
  statically typed, dynamically typed,
  duck-typed?
- What sort of expressions are you
  planning to support? Do you need to
  define an order of operations? Will
  you even have operators?
- What will you use as the run-time
  representation of the program? Will
  you convert the text to a byte-code
  representation, or an AST, or a
  tokenized form of the source text?

There are toolkits available to help take some of the tedium out of the actual parsing of text (ANTLR and Bison, to name two), but I don't know of anything that helps with the actual interpretation part of the task. I'm sure somebody will suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is having a semantics for the language you're implementing -- with that, the implementation becomes straightforward. Otherwise, this question is incredibly broad and hard to answer.

Comment: I don't need a full "answer". I am looking for a discussion about issues and advice on potential pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend Essentials of Programming Languages as a good complement to SICP, particularly if you're interested in interpreters: Official EOPL site. You may want to check out the [third edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262062798)-- the site hasn't been updated for it yet.

Edit: spam prevention is making me choose between links, so the official page is now unheated. It's easily Google-able, though.