# Need some guidance with interpreter creation

Tags: c, memory, interpreter, jit

I am trying to create an interpreter.

My thoughts are to parse the code, transform it into opcodes (very similar to
bytecode, msil etc) and for now to create an interpreter executor and later a JIT engine.

I am currently designing the memory manager and the type system.

I have created a simple memory manager that supports some basic datatypes (integer, float, char, string, array). I can successfully allocate the memory and use it. But I am not satisfied with it. I would like to create a garbage collector, make it object oriented and extend it as much as I can.

I am looking for suggestions, sites, books in order to learn more on this subject.

Comment: This sounds interesting but kind of wide. General compiler textbooks as well as sample code from popular interpreters would be helpful. I can't think of anything specific.

Comment: What does this question have to do with programming?

Comment: @Philip design techniques, software patterns, algorithms.. i believe they are relevant to programming  

@Noufal Ibrahim, yes its wide but i am not trying to write anything for production use.. only for eduction purpose! Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: What language are you writing your interpreter in?

Comment: Take a look at OCaml bytecode interpreter, GC and a memory manager - it is a state of the art implementation, but still quite a simple one, written in a clean and readable C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion: Keep it small. Meaning don't try to do everything that mature interpreters do. Creating a full interpreter is a lot of work. Instead focus on a few small topic that interest you. It looks like you are interested in memory management, so play around with stack, heap, and symbol tables.

References:

- [Writing an Interpreter with Lex, Yacc, and Memphis](http://memphis.compilertools.net/interpreter.html)
- [Writing Compilers and Interpreters book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471113530)
- there is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926835/how-to-write-an-interpreter) question on Stack Overflow
- [How to Write an Interpreter in One Day](http://rpal.sourceforge.net/oneday.html)
- [Writing an Interpreter](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/154039-writing-an-interpreter)

Answer (score 1):

I would ask you to look at **Quincy** - a C interpreter by Al Stevens, complete with an IDE and debugger. His articles appeared in DDJ in 90s. You can [find his articles using Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=site%3Addj.com+quincy&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=).